Draw on an Icosahedron faces with RenderText (three.js)
I was looking at a three.js example where the writer draws numbers on each of the faces of an icosahedron using a canvas and a Three.CanvasTexture:
https://hofk.de/main/discourse.threejs/2021/NumberedIcosahedron/NumberedIcosahedron.html
I wondered if it was possible to extend the example to have more complex drawings on each face, or even animations. I discovered the RenderTexture component in drei and the example shown there:
https://drei.docs.pmnd.rs/portals/render-texture
It shows how to use RenderTexture to draw a complex animation on the faces of a cube.
I am attempting to combine the two examples to use RenderTexture to draw on an Icosahedron. I imagine I need to use RenderTexture to create a similar 1024x64 texture, just like in the first example. Then adopt the same uv mapping. I imagine that will produce the same result as the first example, but with the power of whatever RenderTexture can render. I got to the following point:
import { Canvas } from '@react-three/fiber'
import {
  RenderTexture,
  OrbitControls,
  Text,
  OrthographicCamera
} from '@react-three/drei'
import { suspend } from 'suspend-react'

const inter = import('@pmndrs/assets/fonts/inter_regular.woff')

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Canvas camera={{ position: [5, 5, 5], fov: 25 }}>
      <ambientLight intensity={0.5} />
      <directionalLight position={[10, 10, 5]} />
      <Icosahedron />
      <OrbitControls />
    </Canvas>
  )
}

const numbers = [
  ...Array(20)
    .keys()
    .map((n) => n + 1)
]

const step = 1024 / 20
const start = step * 0.5

const uvs = new Float32Array(120)
for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
  uvs[i * 6] = (0.067 + i) / 20
  uvs[i * 6 + 1] = 0.25
  uvs[i * 6 + 2] = (0.933 + i) / 20
  uvs[i * 6 + 3] = 0.25
  uvs[i * 6 + 4] = (0.5 + i) / 20
  uvs[i * 6 + 5] = 1
}

function Icosahedron() {
  return (
    <mesh>
      <icosahedronGeometry args={[1, 0]}>
        <bufferAttribute
          attach="attributes-uv"
          count={60}
          array={uvs}
          itemSize={2}
        />
      </icosahedronGeometry>
      <meshStandardMaterial>
        <RenderTexture attach="map" width={1024} height={64}>
          <OrthographicCamera
            makeDefault
            args={[0, 1024, 0, 64, 1, 10]}
            position={[0, 0, 5]}
          />
          <color attach="background" args={['#111']} />
          <ambientLight intensity={0.5} />
          <directionalLight position={[10, 10, 5]} />
          {numbers.map((n, i) => (
            <Text
              key={`text_${i}`}
              position={[start + step * i, 0, 0]}
              color="#FFF"
              anchorX="center"
              anchorY="middle"
              font={suspend(inter).default}
              fontSize={20}>
              {`${n}`}
            </Text>
          ))}
        </RenderTexture>
      </meshStandardMaterial>
    </mesh>
  )
}

However, the numbers draw are distorted and not in the correct positions. Am I approaching the problem in the correct way? Is RenderTexture even the right thing to use here? With the goal of drawing complex, animating faces on an icosahedron or similar shape.
